# Statement regarding mean value theorem for harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $u$ is a function that is harmonic on a domain $D$. Could someone offer a proof of the following statement?

> $$ u(z_0) = \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\iint_{\{z-z_0\}<r} u(x+iy) \, dx\, dy $$
>
> for $z_0 \in D$.

Comment: I've been using the mean value theorem for harmonic functions, but I can't seem to get it into this form.

Comment: What is the form you know?

Comment: $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} u(z+\rho e^{i\theta}) \, d\theta$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Transform the integral to polar coordinates, i. e.
\begin{align*}
   \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_{\{z-z_0\} < r} u(x+iy)\, d(x,y)
    &= \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_0^r \int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+\rho e^{i\theta})\,d\theta\,\rho \,d\rho
\end{align*}
Now use what you know (see your comment above).

Comment: Still confused on how to manipulate it to get it into the correct form...

Comment: By your comment above, the inner integral equals $2\pi u(z_0)$